# Firing an event

Tags: c#, events, handler

I can't fire an event. Here is my code.
I tell it that the value I want to know changing is Value with this line:

```
eventvaluechange.IntValue = value;//link value as the value I want to    see change
```

Then I tell what it will do when the value change happend.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int value=0;
    int value2=999;
    Val_changeInt eventvaluechange;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        eventvaluechange = new Val_changeInt();
        eventvaluechange.IntValue = value;//link value as the value I want to see change
        eventvaluechange.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(ValueHasChanged);//what I do on event
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        value = value +1;
    }
    private void ValueHasChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        value2 = value;
        label1.Text = value2.ToString();
    }
    class Val_changeInt
    {
        private int valueToWatchOn;
        public event System.EventHandler ValueChanged;
        protected object _lock = new object();
        protected virtual void ValueHasChanged()
        {
            EventHandler eventvaluechange = ValueChanged;
            if (eventvaluechange != null) eventvaluechange(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        public int IntValue
        {
            get { return this.valueToWatchOn; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.valueToWatchOn)
                {//if value changed enter
                    this.valueToWatchOn = value;
                    ValueHasChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }//Event handler for a value change
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried to debug step by step the code and see what's happening?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, it never get in intvalue.

Comment: Firing an event. It's clear no?

Comment: Your problematic line assigns the value of value to IntValue. What link do you imagine has been established?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
eventvaluechange.IntValue = value;//link value as the value I want to see change
```

Does not what you think it does. There is no link between `eventvaluechange.IntValue` and `value` since it involves a value-type, and therefore the value is just copied, no reference is being copied.

To make this work, you have to use the value-holder that you have instantiated, `eventvaluechange`, since that instance holds the value that will fire the event when the value changes. Like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    eventvaluechange.IntValue = eventvaluechange.IntValue + 1;
}
private void ValueHasChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    value2 = eventvaluechange.IntValue;
    label1.Text = value2.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bit too much going on with that code!

If it's just a single value thats changing, you should maybe re-think your plan of attack and look at implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, which will raise an event for you if it detects a change (you'll still need to do some work on the setter of the property for this to actually work!).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to continue with events which are easy enough to get going, I tend to work off a temple which never fails me:

public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

then where the value has changed, call:
ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, e);      (new C# v6 syntax)

or to use custom event args to pass the new value back to the listener:
public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

then call:
ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, new ValueArgs(newValue));

ValueArgs is declared as such:

```
public class ValueArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool ValueUpdated { get; set; }

    public ValueArgs() { }
    public ValueArgs(int valueUpdated)
    {
        ValueUpdated = valueUpdated;
    }
}
```

and if you ever manually assign an event:

eventvaluechange.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(ValueHasChanged);

Then don't forget to unassign it when the form is closed/disposed!

eventvaluechange.ValueChanged -= new EventHandler(ValueHasChanged);

As these can often cause memory leaks if you forget!!!